# How to lazy load when listening to value events?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a summarization live view dashboard for a huge amount (around 100K) of data points. The current version works correctly in monitoring changes in real-time after initial load, but the dashboard has no data for about 4 seconds on first-load.

The data has been denormalized so `by_date` has a structure like the one bellow, each date holding thousands of `uid` keys, only las available date being relevant for the dashboard.

```
{
   [date: string]: {
      [uid: string]: {
         values: number;
         status: boolean;
      };
   };
}
```

The live listening function is the one bellow.

```js
function observe() {
           db.ref("by_date")
             .orderByValue()
             .limitToLast(1) // only last available date is loaded
             .on("value", function (dataSnapshot) {
                const data = dataSnapshot.val();
                // data json object is put in a state variable
                // changes on the state will trigger a parial dashboard refresh
                setLastDayReportsDb(data); 
            });
      }
```

What I'm trying to find is a way to bring in the data as a stream or paginated, but still keep listening for any changes in values so the realtime live aspect of the dashboard is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually there is a way to lazy load your data and listen changes...

Lets say you have 100 unread chat messages, there can be more incoming unread messages and you want to listen them 10 by 10.

Here is the idea, you need a custom hook that listens real time changes, this custom hook has a one parameter which is lets say "loadby: number".
Every time the Flatlist hits the end we should find a way to unmount that hook and mount again.

Here is the sample code.

This is the hook that listens changes

```js
const useChatListListener = (counted: number) => {
    const [list, setList] = useState<ChatInterface.ChatListItem[]>()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const uid = commonmethods.getUID();
        let onValueChange: any = null

        onValueChange = database.ref(`/chats/${uid}`).orderByChild('read').equalTo(false).limitToFirst(counted).on('value', (snapshot: any) => {
            // listening should return an empty array at least, in this way we understand the first listening is occured.

            const modifiedresponse = commonmethods.createArrayFromObject<ChatInterface.ChatListItem>(snapshot.val())
            if(snapshot) setList(modifiedresponse)
            else setList([])
        })

        return () => {
            if(onValueChange) {
                database.ref(`/chats/${uid}`).off('value', onValueChange);
            }
        }
    }, [])

    return list
}
```

And this is the actual flatlist will be lazyload and listens changes

```js
interface ListenerComponentProps {
    counted: number
    callback: (data: any) => void
}

const ChatListenerManager: React.FC<ListenerComponentProps> = (props) => {
    const listdata = useChatListListener(props.counted)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("I AM IN")
        
        return () => {
            console.log("I AM OUT")
        };
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        props.callback(listdata)

    }, [listdata])

    return null
}

interface Props {}

const LOAD_BY = 10
const ChatList: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const [reload, setReload] = useState({ status: true, by: 10 })
    const [listData, setListData] = useState<ChatInterface.ChatListItem[]>()
    const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(false)
    const [bottomloading, setBottomLoading] = useState(false)
    const [keepLoading, setKeepLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!reload.status) {
            /**
             * If you hit bottom and the requested number is greater than returned array length
             * then we shouldn't update the next requested number and also we should allow to request again when hitting to end too
             * There could be more incoming unread messages so there is no end actually.
             */
            setReload({ status: true, by: keepLoading ? reload.by + LOAD_BY : reload.by })
        }
    }, [reload])

    const listListener = (data: ChatInterface.ChatListItem[]) => {
        if(data && data.length >= 0) {
            setListData(data)
            if(reload.by > data.length) setKeepLoading(false)
            !initialLoad && setInitialLoad(true)
        }
    }

    const loadMore = () => {
        setReload({ status: false, by: reload.by })
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            // This is the actual listener and lazy loader, this does the both thing together
            {reload.status && <ChatListenerManager counted={reload.by} callback={listListener} />}

            {
                    <FlatList
                        data={listData}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <ChatListItem {...item} />}
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        onEndReached={() => {
                            if(initialLoad && !bottomloading) loadMore()
                        }}
                    />
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

This way we have component which uses a listener hook, and we are mounting & unmounting it when we hit the bottom. When we increase the number of "counted" it loads more chat messages and listens them too.
Importantly also when we unmount it, we safely remove the listener too, no side effect.